# transformation for non-constant variance?

Tags: regression, variance, data-transformation, nonlinear

This is from my textbook

[image]

I don't understand what does the content in red mean, for example, what does $y^2_i \infty  \sigma_i$ mean? How can we tell the relationship between $y^2_i$ and $\sigma_i$ by looking at the residual plot?(I don't actually know the symbol between $y^2_i$ and $\sigma_i$, so I use $\infty$ instead). 
Another question is, for the first one, why is not $E[y^2_i]=a+bx$ rather than $E[1/y]=a+bx$?

Comment: The symbol $\propto$ (`$\propto$`) can be read as "is [proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29#Direct_proportionality) to".

Answer (score 7):

> for example, what does $y^2_i\propto σ_i$ mean?

The part in the red box looks looks backward to me. I think what they're actually trying to say there is "If $\sigma_i\propto y_i^2$" (the proportionality was fine but they make it sound like it's being driven by the wrong thing is all - we're basically estimating how the spread changes as the mean changes (note that the plot is vs $x$ rather than $y$, so arguably it should be "If $\sigma_i\propto E(y_i)^2$" but I won't harp on that issue for now). Note that the display to the right is $r_i$ vs $x_i$ and see that $\sigma_i$ is the population standard deviation of the $i$-th error term (which terms we estimate by residuals), and since the spread is increasing quadratically in $x_i$ it is at least potentially possible for it to be proportional to $y_i^2$ (it requires that point of zero variance to be at a particular place on the x-axis).

Note that you need the $y$'s to all be positive for this to make sense.

If that proportionality ($\sigma_i=k y_i^2$) were the case, then via a Taylor expansion, $Var(1/y_i)$ will be [approximately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables#Second_moment) $1/E(y_i)^4 \sigma_i^2 = k^2$, a constant; this choice of a transformation to make the variance approximately constant is typically referred to as a *variance-stabilizing transformation*.

There are a number of posts on site relating to Taylor expansions and variance stabilizing transformations.

If spread was proportional to $y_i$ rather than its square, you might consider taking logs and if it was proportional to $\sqrt{y_i}$ you might consider taking square roots.

(There are alternatives to transformation, however, that may well be more suitable in many cases)

Similarly for the second red box; taking $y^2$ would again (to first order) stabilize the variance when the relationship between variance and mean is reciprocal for the same reason.

---

*Beware, however* -- there's no clear reason to expect the relationship on the transformed scale to be linear. Indeed if it were linear before transformation (and it must have been the case - at least to a good approximation - for the residual plot to be useful in the way we're being asked to use it) then it won't generally be linear after transformation.

> How can we tell the relationship between $y^2_i$ and $σ_i$ by looking at the residual plot?

Look at how the spread changes on average with the increase in $x$ (and hence $y$).